# SQL - AT TIME ZONE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timezone

I have this query that correctly returns the Central European Time as +2 hours. However, it does not add these two hours to the time. 
How do I add these two hours time (or x hours depending on time zone)?

```
DECLARE @targettimezone AS sysname = 'Central European Standard Time'
SELECT convert(datetime2,'2018-10-25T13:43:19.296Z') AT TIME ZONE @targettimezone;
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: `SELECT convert(datetime2,convert(datetimeoffset,'2018-10-25T13:43:19.296Z') AT TIME ZONE @targettimezone);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use [datetimeoffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of `datetime2`.

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of a day that has time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock.

Then convert the `datetimeoffset` to `DateTime` can get your expect the result.

```
DECLARE @targettimezone AS sysname = 'Central European Standard Time'
SELECT cast(cast('2018-10-25T13:43:19.296Z' as datetimeoffset) AT TIME ZONE @targettimezone as datetime2);
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=99544746482b3ac25265e94af1007fbb)

Comment: This still comes back with the `+02:00` bit though, is that desired?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ok thank for point out cast to `DateTime` type again can make it.

Answer (score 4):

Let's give the engine some help:

```
DECLARE @targettimezone AS sysname = 'Central European Standard Time'
SELECT convert(datetime2,'2018-10-25T13:43:19.296Z') 
    AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
    AT TIME ZONE @targettimezone;
```

I'd expect the format that you specified for your timestamp to be interpreted as UTC natively, but it doesn't seem to be. So the above is just explicit about it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the offset using the `DATEPART` function in SQL Server then apply it to your UTC time.

```
DECLARE @utcDateTime DATETIME = '2018-10-25T13:43:19.296Z'
DECLARE @targetTimeZone AS SYSNAME = 'Central European Standard Time'

DECLARE @offsetMinutes INT
DECLARE @targetDateTime DATETIME

--Get the offset value in minutes
SET @offsetMinutes = DATEPART(tz, CONVERT(DATETIME2, @utcDateTime) AT TIME ZONE 
@targettimezone)
--Add the offset to the UTC time
SET @targetDateTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, @offsetMinutes, @utcDateTime)

--No you have the value in the target time zone
SELECT @targetDateTime
```